# Automation Anywhere - task won't execute on logged off state

Tags: automationanywhere

I have already set up the auto-login settings and checked the bypass legal disclaimer. I am getting this message: AAE was unable to unlock or logon onto the machine xxxx

-AAE Auto Login Service is running

-It only works in locked state. This previously worked and noticed it wasn't when I changed my windows password (password updated in auto-login settings).

-I also ran the Auto-Login diagnostic utility I found in their website --no issue

-We are using AAE 10.5 on Windows Server 2012 R2.

Your feedback will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting the machine solves the auto-login issue. But need to find a workaround as we don't want to restart the server every time we change passwords.